# Local Variable to validate remote operation

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am trying to validate that a remote machine can connect to another machine on a specific port

Pseudo Code

```
$RemoteSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName MyRemoteVM

Invoke-Command -Session $RemoteSession -ScriptBlock {$RsTestResults = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient -Argument 2ndRemoteVM , 2ndRemoteVMPort}
```

However, I can't seem to get the results of that test
I have tried adding another Invoke-Command like below, but it is not helping

```
$LocalResults = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {$RsTestResults}
```

any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $RemoteSession -ScriptBlock {
    $RsTestResults = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient -ArgumentList 2ndRemoteVM, 2ndRemoteVMPort
}
```

The variable `$RsTestResults` is being created on the remote host and its scope will be said host. If you want the results of `System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient` to be stored on your local host, you would need to store the results of `Invoke-Command` like below:

```
$RsTestResults = Invoke-Command -Session $RemoteSession -ScriptBlock {
    New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient -ArgumentList 2ndRemoteVM, 2ndRemoteVMPort
}
```

---

#### Edit

To explain the error message you're getting:

```
PS > New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient -ArgumentList $null, $null
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "The requested address is not valid in its context xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:0"
```

Which means, the variables for `IPAddress` and `Port` are never being passed to `Invoke-Command`.

You have 2 options to pass those variables to the cmdlet, one is with `$using:variableName` and the other is with `-ArgumentList`.

Assuming you have **2 local variables**, for example:

```
$ipAddress = $csv.IPAddress
$port = $csv.Port
```

- With [`$using:variableName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.1#example-9--include-local-variables-in-a-command-run-on-a-remote-computer)

```
$RsTestResults = Invoke-Command -Session $RemoteSession -ScriptBlock {
    New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient -ArgumentList $using:ipAddress, $using:port
}
```

- With [`-ArgumentList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.1#example-11--use-the-param-keyword-in-a-script-block)

```
$RsTestResults = Invoke-Command -Session $RemoteSession -ScriptBlock {
    param($ipAddress, $port)
    New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient -ArgumentList $ipAddress, $port
} -ArgumentList $ipAddress, $port
```

Comment: This won't quite work - powershell will serialize the resulting object and you won't be able to interact with the client in the local session.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen you're right, the object would lose its methods due to serialization. I should've pointed that out, my bad. But if OP is just trying to know if the port is open I think this would suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the responses folks. However, I am still not getting it (sorry in advance)

Comment: Thanks for the responses folks. 
However, I am still not getting it (sorry in advance). When I change the code to : $RsTestResults = Invoke-Command -Session $RemoteSession - ScriptBlock {New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient - Argument 2ndRemoteVM, 2ndRemotePort}   

I receive an error New-Object: Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s) "The requested address is not valid in its context [ip address]:0

Comment: @TallKewlOnez `2ndRemoteVM` and `2ndRemoteVMPort` are hardcoded values or are variables being passed to `Invoke-Command`? If so, how are you passing those variables? On the other hand, from reading the error message, there seem to be an extra space in `- Argument` (it should be `-Argument`).

Comment: They are passed as variables. I read in a csv and then traverse the resulting table via foreach.. 

foreach (item in requirements) { gives me item.servertocheck & item.porttocheck)

the -Argument portion does not have a space in the code, I have to manually type the code here as I cant access the internet in my work environment

Comment: @TallKewlOnez see my last edit, hopefully it explains what you're missing.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thanks That worked!!

Comment: @TallKewlOnez happy to help. If the answer was helpful, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)